# Jquery UI Datepicker doesn't show again when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, javascript-framework

I seem to have this working except for the fact that once the link is clicked, the datepicker opens, then I select a date and all is good and well, then once I try to click the link again, the date picker does not open again.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>

<head>

<!-- LOAD JQUERY LIBRARY: -->  
    <link   href="jq/jquery-ui.css"         type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="jq/jquery.min.js"          type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="jq/jquery-ui.min.js"       type="text/javascript"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function test() { 

var datePickerValue = null; 

$("#d1").datepicker().datepicker("show").change(function () 
{ 
    $('#d1').datepicker({onSelect:  datePickerValue = $(this).val() }).hide();

  alert("You picked: " + datePickerValue);
}); 



} 


</script>



</head>

<body>

<div id="d1"></div>
<a href="javascript:test()">test</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the show method before the datepicker() as like below:

```
$("#d1").show().unbind().datepicker().datepicker("show").change(function ()  { 
   $('#d1').datepicker({onSelect:  datePickerValue = $(this).val() }).hide();
   alert("You picked: " + datePickerValue);
});
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks very much to Kundan. This works great, I notice though that the alert box, once a date has been selected, popups up like 2 or 3 more times. What will cause that, and what can be done to fix that behaviour such that the alert box only pops up only once?

Comment: use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) for it.

Comment: @JasonKelly, i re-checked your code and i noticed it is because you are binding datepicker to div on each click again and again. So in that case just unbind it first and then bind again. I have updated my answer please have a look.

Comment: Wow! whatever you did, it worked like a charm. A great and big huge thank you!!!! So amazed to have wonderful, smart and beyond intelligent people like you out there. Thanks so very much. Your a genious!

Answer (score 0):

```
function test() {
    $('#d1').datepicker({onSelect: function(){alert("You picked: " + $(this).val())})} ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i am completely off the mark here but you might have more success if you use, jquery .on - http://api.jquery.com/on/

so add a id or class to your link:

```
<a class="clicky" href="#">test</a>
```

then call your function like this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".clicky", test);
```

I think this will solve your issue but I may be wrong